# Finding a column value where columnID equals xxxx in JSON using C#

Tags: c#, json, smartsheet-api

I am using C# to grab values from a JSON file and put them into a database. I am new to JSON and so don't really know too much of how to work with it. I will do my best to explain the structure I have and what I am trying to do. But to sum up I am trying to call a variable from JSON in a similar way you would do in an SQL Where statement. So grab this value where this other value = x.

So the JSON format is as follows. 
Firstly it idenfitifies the columns.

```
"columns": [
    {
      "id": 8098453499733892,
      "index": 0,
      "title": "Task Name",
      "type": "TEXT_NUMBER",
      "format": ",,,,,,2,,,,,,,,,1",
      "primary": true,
      "width": 378
    },
    {
      "id": 780104105256836,
      "index": 1,
      "title": "KPI (RYG)",
      "type": "PICKLIST",
      "symbol": "RYG",
      "options": [
        "Red",
        "Yellow",
        "Green"
      ],.....
```

Then the rows and cells within that:

```
"id": 2157159933863812,
      "rowNumber": 2,
      "parentRowNumber": 1,
      "parentId": 7786659468076932,
      "expanded": false,
      "format": ",,1,,,,,,,22,,,,,,",
      "createdAt": "2015-03-04T15:58:28+13:00",
      "modifiedAt": "2015-03-04T15:58:32+13:00",
      "cells": [
        {
          "columnId": 8098453499733892,
          "type": "TEXT_NUMBER",
          "value": "GLH Toll MASTER FROM WEEK 47",
          "displayValue": "GLH Toll MASTER FROM WEEK 47",
          "format": ",,1,,,,2,,,22,,,,,,1"
        },
        {
          "columnId": 2750428942231428,
          "type": "CHECKBOX",
          "value": true,
          "format": ",,1,,,,,,,22,,,,,,"
        },
```

Ok so for an example. What I want to do is grab the columnID value in the cell, and then use that to find the title value in the column. So in the above example, I would want to find 'title' where id in column equals 8098453499733892, which would give me the result of 'Task Name'.

I don't even know if this is possible but have struggled to find a working example on the web. FYI I am using smartsheets.

Comment: You can Deserialize it to specific object then find the title by LINQ expression

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone looking I used the where clause in the select token. Here is the code that I used to find the column title based on an id value.

```
var test = jObject.SelectToken("columns").Where(t => t["id"].Value<Int64>() == 5283703732627332).FirstOrDefault()["title"].Value<string>();
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to create an equivalent object/class in your c# containing those properties in your JSON. In order to get the columnID column based on your JSON structure, you need to create the the class below:

```
class Class1 {
     public string id { get; set; }
     public int rowNumber { get; set; }
     public int parentId { get; set; }
     public bool expanded { get; set; }
     public string format{ get; set; }
     public List <Cells> cells {get; set;}
}

class Cells {
  public string columnId {get; set;}
  public string type{get; set;}
  public bool value{get; set;}
  public string format {get; set;}
```

}

You need to deserialize the JSON string from the API using the Class1 object and from there you can access whatever column that you need.

Comment: This was helpful but didn't really answer my question. I am trying to get the cell value where the column ID is equal to a specific ID.